# multilingual dialogflow not working in web deployment

Tags: dialogflow-es

I implemented a basic two language intent in dialogflow. English (default language) and French. If I say goodbye (or equivalent) it says something to me in English. If I say au revoir (or equivalent in French), it says something to me in French.

It works fine in the test environment (the dialogflow console) but when I deploy to the web it only works in English.

Comment: you may need to post relevant code to get good responses ..

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed this error as well. Apparently as of now we can only successfully test it within the actions on google simulator console and dialogflow, the web demo version only works for the default language.

There is a good medium post by Wassim you can find [here](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/build-multi-lingual-actions-for-the-google-assistant-106d2b94aa1a), it guides you to build multi-lingual Actions for the Google Assistant.